# How can i manage many servers in just one domain like google and facebook

Tags: dns, vps

My problem is how can i  manage my servers in different ips using just using one domain and same name such as  google Have many servers but using just one domain like gmail , youtube and cloud .
How can i make it happen

Answer (score 0):

This is done by adding in front of all the servers load balance. And assign the domain to this LB.

Also you can add resolve to the same hostname as many IP addresses. (try to exec `nslookup google.com` and you will see)

For loadbalancing mail servers you can play with weight parameter in MX records in DNS

Comment: Thank you but how can i resolve load balance for mail servers in different accounts like google ??

Comment: Loadbalancing of mail servers is a different story. Check for DNS MX records. You do not need LB in such sense as for httpd servers.